# How to update disabled prop on checkbox change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, attr, prop

I have a checkbox that I'm using to toggle whether a li tag gets added to a list. When it is added to the list other li tags and their associated checkboxes (nested under the li tag) are "disabled" using jQuery.

The checkbox will become disabled but it does not un disable when I uncheck the box currently.

I've tried prop, attr, removeProp/Attr which no success in making the checkbox active again.

```
$('#id_of_ul_that_holds_li's').on('change', li.active input, function() {

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(this).parent().addClasss('checked')
      $(this).children('input').prop('disabled', true)
    }
    else if (!($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(this).parent().removeClasss('checked')
      $(this).children('input').prop('disabled', false)
    }

  });
```

Comment: `if( $(this).is(':checked') )`. But be sure you're referring to the checkbox and not a div

Comment: Or `this.checked`...

Comment: That runs fine. Everything else in that if condition runs. It's only the disabled updating that is not working.

Comment: I'm using .children('input'). I forgot to add that

Comment: Ok, one thing I'm seeing is you have `'#id_of_div'`, which makes me think that `this` is not actually a checkbox.

Comment: Right. I'm using .children to select it.

Comment: Not in `$(this).prop('checked')`... and `div` elements do not have a native `checked` property, so unless you've got code that's artificially setting that element's non-native `checked` property, I don't think your `if` is working as well as you think it is..

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Just updated it so its as close to the actual code as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested:

```
$("#id_of_div").on('change', "li.active > input[type='checkbox']", function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().addClasss('checked')
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
  } else {
    $(this).parent().removeClasss('checked')
    $(this).prop('disabled', false)
  }
});
```

This will check if the Checkbox Element, `this`, is `checked`. See more:

- https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector

Comment: The if condition works fine. Everything else in it works. It's the updating of the checkbox that does not work. The checkbox is not on (this)

Comment: @TaylorDorsett see the updates. Make sure you have the right inital selector.

Comment: @TaylorDorsett there is also a logic error. If you Disable the checkbox, you can no longer Click it again to execute the `change` event; as it is disabled. So You can only ever disable them but never click them to become enabled.

Comment: Just updated the code so its as close to the actual code as possible

Comment: @TaylorDorsett your code makes less sense at this time. You're looking for a Change event on a DIV element? You also have a Syntax error in your Selector now.

Comment: change event on a ul

Comment: @TaylorDorsett Change event cannot happen on `ul` either. I do see you're delegating to an `input` element. Since you do this, you do not need to call the `.children()`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: I ended up needing to call this elsewhere and adding .children() to it but you pointing out that I was deligating to an input element was helpful in me tracking this down. Thank you.